# Where is the Zombie info shown once activated?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode 4.2, I have turned on the Zombie detection in the Scheme Run diagnostics (the only option checked in that window), but when I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS, nothing is shown in the debugger. Where is the zombie info shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the zombie detection code finds a zombie, it logs into the console (Cmd-Shift-Y). It doesn’t always work, that’s probably why you’re not seeing anything reported for your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I’m not sure what the circumstances for successful zombie report are, maybe someone could shed a light on that.

Answer (score 0):

When you use simulator, you can run Instruments (command+i) and there you will be able to choose `Zombies`. When application will encounter bad access, it will show you exact message and exact place in code responsible for this error.

Comment: In instruments, it just does the crash; I have the Allocations timeline running in the Zombies profiler, but there are no messages. Where are they located?  If not using instruments, there is presumably another way to view Zombies as well, using the method I mentioned in my question, but I don't know where that information reports either. (and why are there more than one method for zombie detection? makes it very confusing)

Comment: in my case there was a popup with very precise data about this error and variable causing it. If there aren't any susuggestions, I would try to set some breakpoints to analise exactly where problem is